# Trying to combine postgres functions returning tables into 1 function returning json

Tags: json, postgresql, function

I have multiple functions that all return the same data structure in a table.  I have 1 function that calls all of them via a UNION and it returns the results in a table format.  How do I get that 1 function to return the results from all the subfunctions in a json?

I tried doing:

```
SELECT row_to_json(t) from (select col1, col2, col3 from db.subfunction1())
UNION
SELECT row_to_json(t) from (select col1, col2, col3 from db.subfunction2())
UNION
SELECT row_to_json(t) from (select col1, col2, col3 from db.subfunction3());
```

and got

> ERROR:  Could not identify an equality operator for type json LINE 1:
> select row_to_json(t) from (select..........
> ^ SQL state: 42883 Character: 8

OKay, so I run the following:
Select * from db.subfunction1();

The result is a table

| data type | A date | some text | Another text field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Something | 2021-01-31 | detail info | ip4: 5663773; |

Each function does the same thing.  I want the parent function to convert the output to JSON.

Comment: You have more `(` than `)` is this correct ?   Please, can you share expected results, and the definition of the functions `db.subfunction1()`, `db.subfunction2()` and `db.subfunction3()`

Comment: Each of the child functions return a text, date, text, and text fields in that order.  All of them look at different schemas with tables that are identical.  I did not notice that the parentheses are missing in my question, just a typo on my part.  I want the output from those child functions (defined as returning a table) to be returned in json format from the parent function.

Comment: Help us help you, and share the output from `select col1, col2, col3 from db.subfunction1()`

Comment: Try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` which won't need an equality operator. Unless you actually need to filter for duplicates?

Comment: I ended up using the UNION ALL and got some more assistance from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220409/postgres-return-json-from-a-function.  Overthinking things is a bad habit of mine.  Simple SQL function was all I needed to call the other 3 child functions and I got the output I needed.  Thanks to EVERYONE here who helped me.  MUCH APPRECIATED!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still pretty unclear, but let's try to repeat the `row_to_json()` on the results of the 3 unions:

```sql
WITH abc as (
   SELECT 'Something' as col1,  '2021-01-31' as col2,   'detail info' as col3),
  def as (
   select 1 as i,row_to_json(abc) as j from abc
     union all
   select 2,row_to_json(abc) from abc
     union all
   select 3,row_to_json(abc) from abc
  )
select row_to_json(x) from (
select def.j as a, d2.j as b, d3.j as c
from def
inner join def d2 on d2.i=2
inner join def d3 on d3.i=3 
where def.i=1) x;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/txBHObkQ)

result:

```
{"a":{"col1":"Something","col2":"2021-01-31","col3":"detail info"},"b":{"col1":"Something","col2":"2021-01-31","col3":"detail info"},"c":{"col1":"Something","col2":"2021-01-31","col3":"detail info"}}
```